# Animated closing of Backbone Marionette views

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I wanted my Marionette views to close in an animated fashion and wait for the animation to finish before removing them from the DOM.
(Insights will be highly appreciated)

I've rewritten Marionette.View close method in the following way:

```js
close: function(){
        if (this.isClosed) { return; }

        // allow the close to be stopped by returning `false`
        // from the `onBeforeClose` method
        var beforeCloseReturnValue = this.triggerMethod("before:close");
        if (beforeCloseReturnValue === false){
            return;
        }

        if (IsObjectNullOrUndefined(beforeCloseReturnValue))
        {
            this.closeTheView();
            return;
        }

        if (beforeCloseReturnValue.promise)
        {
            var _this = this;
            $.when(beforeCloseReturnValue).done(function(){
                console.log("view close done!");
                _this.closeTheView();
            });
        }
    },

closeTheView: function(){
    // mark as closed before doing the actual close, to
    // prevent infinite loops within "close" event handlers
    // that are trying to close other views
    this.isClosed = true;
    this.triggerMethod("close");

    // unbind UI elements
    this.unbindUIElements();

    // remove the view from the DOM
    this.remove();
 }
```

And the view instance contains the following implementation for the onBeforeClose method:

```js
onBeforeClose: function(){
  _this = this;
  return $.Deferred(function(){
    _this.$el.fadeOut(2000, dfd.resolve);
    }).promise();
}
```

Works quite well so far.
Wanted to hear if you have any thought about it.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this and came up with more or less the same solution.

It works, but I don't like 2 things:
1) It's geared specially towards closing of views. A more general solution to animations would be nice.
2) If one uses CSS animations (by swapping classes) and they change the timing in css, then they need to manually update the promises (which can get messy on large applications).

I think the way AngularJS deals with animations works well and effectively deals with above 2 problems. But maybe it doesn't fit the Marionette/Backbone unopinionated style...